# How I can get the Call Quality of all teams Calls&Meetings by Graph Api or similar?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, notifications, httprequest, webhooks

I worked on a solution for getting all teams audio & video communication quality in the company.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/5-exercise-change-notifications

On Runtime-Ecxceptions I use the old version the videos are created. [older sources](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications/tree/live)
That should solved later but it should no reason for getting onl some notifications not all.

I tried to get the callrecords by change notification  and it worked partly, but I get not all notifications, and the endpoint handler work more than a half day (12, 14 or 16 h i think).

If I understand it correct. All cloud communication audio-/Video Call was accessed with https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/
If the CallRecord is an meeting type the the joinWebURL is set and must be added to the filter-clause to get the corresponding meeting.

- All online meetings are missing
- some group calls direct routing calls
- and PSTN-Calls I have not tested it.

My Created subscription:

```
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://a283-178-27-237-107.ngrok.io/api/notifications",
  "resource": "/communications/callRecords",
  "expirationDateTime": "2021-08-29T11:00:00.0000000Z"
}
```

I took on every creation or renewing the subscription the max time 4230, but I tried it with short timespawn and periodically renewing the subscription.

My setting in the registered App

```
// add permissions to registered app
CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All
CallRecords.Read.All
Calls.AccessMedia.All
Directory.Read.All
OnlineMeetings.Read.All
OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All
Reports.Read.All
User.Read.All
(OnlineMeetings is only a short    time added)
```

I set the application access policy for this app with powershell.

Then I tried to get the Callrecords through the Callrecords History of teams Admin Center.
But the Id's there worked party an with the user who created the Meeting or call.

I got the messages Forbidden, invalid token,... so it seems the app works on with delgate permission, but I set App permission.That could clarify why i cannot all CallRedcords.if Icreated a subscription for a app which has appermision, the webook should called on ever Call.

So have 2 big problem:

1. Why there are not all notifications send?
2. How can i get an valid access token which works with app permissions and not with delegate permissions?

Update:
Now it seems i get all notifications, point 1 & 2 or irrelvant?
not use  postman accessing subscriptions, i get no valid token for postman what ever I tried (Oauth2 Authentification copying token from the notificationurl handler), it seems the effect of the applicatiobn access policy.
Has anybody a solution for that?

Update 15.09.2021:

CallRecords Records seems  to work fine, there was an error on postman enviroment.
I ignored other manuals and followed the steps  to use postman from microsoft  for that (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/use-postman). Creating subscription  with the application permission and it seems I get all notifications.

So getting all notification seems to work. So I will close it now.

Comment: I get no soultion for using Postman since activating the application access rule , the only way I found is make  an graph aopi tool with same authentification routines as the notification handler. But if there is way to authentificate postman tto work such apps  I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CallRecords Records seems to work fine, there was an error on postman enviroment. I ignored other manuals and followed the steps to use postman from microsoft for that (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/use-postman). Creating subscription with the application permission and it seems I get all notifications.

So getting all notification seems to work.
So I could close it generally, beacuse concerning question in this context needs own questions.

A controll check  if I get all notification is the onyl open point on this question.
So I wait a few days, if there is no answer I close this question.